# Child directive template not updating after scope change

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom directive with children directives:

```
<rp-nav>
    <rp-nav-item cat="1"></rp-nav-item>
    <rp-nav-item cat="2"></rp-nav-item>
    <rp-nav-item cat="3"></rp-nav-item>
    <rp-nav-item cat="4"></rp-nav-item>

    <rp-flyout></rp-flyout>
</rp-nav>
```

Here are the modules I have defined:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('rpNav', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.currentItem = 'none'; //initialize currentItem
            this.setCurrentItem = function(itemId) {
                $scope.currentItem = itemId;
            }
        },
    };
});

app.directive('rpNavItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function(el, attrs) {
            return '<p>item {{currentItem}} ' + attrs.cat;
        },
        require: '^rpNav',

        link: function(scope, el, attrs, nav) {
            el.on('click', function() {
                nav.setCurrentItem(attrs.cat);
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive('rpFlyout', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p style="background-color: lightblue">{{currentItem}}</p>'
    };
});
```

The idea is to click in any of the items and make the *rp-flyout* element display information about the clicked *rp-nav-item*. The scope variable ***currentItem*** does change on click, but the template in *rp-flyout* does not update. What am I missing to achieve this goal? And, is this a "best practice" way of tackling this problem.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xHGHoJFewLrcDcXh0cd2)

Comment: Its because your click event doesnt trigger a digest cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the comment, directives are not inherently part of the digest cycle, so you need to add `scope.$apply()` inside your `el.click` handler to trigger a digest cycle and update template bindings.

```
el.on('click', function() {
  nav.setCurrentItem(attrs.cat);
  scope.$apply();
});
```